# What is a word that means both silly and scary?

Tags: single-word-requests

To find music, my friend and I were trying to think of a word that means both silly and scary. She says that she knows she's used it before but can't remember it. Any ideas?

Comment: on a side note, makes me wonder where the phrase "scared silly" comes from...

Comment: Uh, Scooby-Dooby?

Comment: @andi from being scared to the point where one was no longer in full control of ones senses, and hence silly.

Answer (score 8):

> [***FREAKY***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freaky)
>   1. Strange or unusual; *freakish*.
>   2. (slang) ***Frightening***.
>
> [*freakish*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freakish)
>   1. Markedly unusual or abnormal; strange
>   2. Relating to or being a freak
>   3. Capricious or whimsical. (i.e. - ***silly***)

Answer (score 3):

The closest word I can think of is *grotesque* which means comically (or repulsively) ugly.

Answer (score 3):

The words "spooky" and "kooky" come to mind.

Comment: All together *ooky*?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch That is actually *exactly* what came to mind!

Comment: But *spooky = weird, scary*, and *kooky = weird, silly*. They're just two different words with close connotations both to each other and to OP's two target meanings. The request is for a *single* word embodying both meanings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The point of my answer was to give the OP a place to start a thesaurus search if not provide the exactly correct word. I'm not totally sure what your point is.

Comment: I like _spooky_. I don't reckon most dictionaries would mention "silly" in their definitions of the word, but, still, it seems to have a rather juvenile connotation. For example, when I queried `the spooky house` on [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1336&bih=874&q=the+spooky+house&oq=the+spooky+house), a lot of cartoonish houses were returned, like [this one](http://www.stayinwonderland.com/2011/09/the-spooky-house-digital-painting/) from a children's book. I would think that "spooky" could refer to a "silly scariness" in many contexts.

Comment: @ Kevin: OP could just as easily start a thesaurus search with *silly* and *scary*. My point is that suggesting two more (somewhat less common) synonyms for the original words doesn't really constitute an answer, even if they are alliterative.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Eh, I still think "spooky" is closer to what OP was looking for than "freaky", but I'm not going to argue with you. One of the perks of an open forum like this is that you can get a variety of different kinds of answers, not just the kind you personally deem appropriate for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

How about "Eerie"?

> 1. Uncanny, so as to inspire superstitious fear; weird:

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with slang, try **spoopy**:

> "Spoopy" is an Internet slang word used to describe something that is comical and spooky at the same time.
>   <sub>[Know Your Meme](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/spoopy)</sub>

Notably, [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/what-does-spoopy-mean-slang-word-history) published an article about the word (under "Words We're Watching").